# Java make rows and columns

Tags: java, output, system.out

Building a rectangular with character input and specified column and rows. whitespace in the middle.

using standard input for string s, int r, int c

```
private static void printstuff(String s, int r, int c) {

    colums(s, c);
    rows(s, c, r);
    colums(s, c);

}

// straight columns 

private static void colums(String cs, int cc) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= cc; i++) {
        System.out.print(cs);
    }

}
```

this creates desired whitespace or "" to concat string with ie making 
    x""""""""x

```
private static String whitespace(int wc) {
    String ws = " ";
    for (int i = 1; i <= wc - 3; i++) {
        ws += " ";
    }
    return ws;
}
```

whitespace to built a rectangular.

```
// downwards building

private static void rows(String rs, int rc, int rr) {
    String ws = whitespace(rc);
    for (int i = 1; i <= rr - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(rs + ws + rs);

        // put strings together

    }

}
```

}
whitespace and character rows to built a rectangular. needless to say it failed.

sample output:

```
XXXX    X  
X  X  
xxxx
```

desired output:

```
xxxx  
x  x  
xxxx
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is... You should check out [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). It provides many string padding options.

Comment: cheers! sorry should have specified, the white space inserts on the top column

Comment: I'm trying to help you edit your question... If you begin each line with 4 spaces, the whitespace will be preserved.  There's no reason to use dots to represent whitespace!

Comment: I reckon trying to concat string and white spaces with println ie over multiple lines causes some error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one quick solution below.. Cheers

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "X";
    int totalColumns = 4;
    int totalRow = 3;

    colums(s, totalColumns);
    rows(s, totalColumns, totalRow);
    colums(s, totalColumns);


}

private static void colums(String cs, int cc) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cc; i++) {
        System.out.print(cs);
    }

}

private static String whitespace(int tc) {
    String ws = " ";
    for (int i = 1; i < tc - 2; i++) {
        ws += " ";
    }
    return ws;
}

private static void rows(String rs, int tc, int tr) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < tr - 2  ; i++) {
        System.out.println(rs + whitespace(tc) + rs);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this what you want but throw a System.out.println(""); after the for loop in colums

Comment: yeah but that will give me white space only whereas I would need x     x (whitespace inbetween string)

Comment: I just tested it with this and it works. try it out.  private static void colums(String cs, int cc) {
     for (int i = 1; i <= cc; i++) {
         System.out.print(cs);
     }
     System.out.println("");

 }